# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars,

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, selenium

I'm trying to print a df with 5 columns with some info about financial instruments.
The list `no_float_prezzo` is created parsing the web and it contains `text data`.
To create the fifth column (profit/loss column) I would need to do some arithmetical operations with the lists *quantità*, `investimento` and `no_float_prezzo`.
However I can't do this arithmetical operations because Python can't convert the `no_float_prezzo` text data into float.

I tried doing `prezzo = float(no_float_prezzo)` but the terminal gave me the error: `"TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"`

Here's the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np


[...]

################## DATAFRAME #################

asset = ['BTC/EUR', 'Eurostoxx select dividend 30', 'ESPO', 'AcomeA Eurobbligazionario']

***no_float_prezzo = np.array([BTCEUR_price, EUROSTOXXSELECTDIVIDEND30price, ESPOprice, ACOMEAEUROBBprice])***

*prezzo = float(no_float_prezzo)*

quantità = np.array([0.00717041, 48, 28, 32.388], dtype=np.float64)

investimento = np.array([296.4, 1002.24, 986.16, 725], dtype=np.float64)

profit_loss_perc = ((quantità*prezzo-investimento)/investimento)

col = ['asset', 'prezzo', 'quantità', 'investimento']

pd.set_option("display.precision", 8)

df = pd.DataFrame({'asset': asset, 'prezzo': prezzo, 'quantità': quantità, 'investimento': investimento})


print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

I also tried `np.vectorize` but nothing.

Comment: Did you take time to look up the python `float` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Numpy [`astype(dtype)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy-ndarray-astype) function, since Python built-in `float` function only accepts scalar values.

```py
import numpy as np

BTCEUR_price = '-134.56'
EUROSTOXXSELECTDIVIDEND30price = '1.34e2'
ESPOprice = '-193.9e-2'
ACOMEAEUROBBprice = '+843.059485'

no_float_prezzo = np.array([BTCEUR_price, EUROSTOXXSELECTDIVIDEND30price, ESPOprice, ACOMEAEUROBBprice])

prezzo = no_float_prezzo.astype(np.float64)

quantità = np.array([0.00717041, 48, 28, 32.388], dtype=np.float64)
investimento = np.array([296.4, 1002.24, 986.16, 725], dtype=np.float64)
profit_loss_perc = ((quantità*prezzo-investimento)/investimento)

print(profit_loss_perc)
```

```
[-1.00325523  5.41762452 -1.05505395 36.66208359]
```